# Update tableView row from AppDelegate Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, push-notification, appdelegate

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Hello. I have a tableview like in the picture above and I'm receiving some silent push notifications. Depending on them I need to reload a specific cell from the `tableView`. Since I'm getting the `notification` in the `AppDelegate` and there at the moment I'm reloading the whole `tableView`...but personally I don't find this the best solution since I only need to update a specific row.

Any hints please how can I update just a specific cell from appDelegate?

```
if userInfo["notification_type"] as? String == "update_conversation" {
            if let rootVC = (self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.visibleViewController {
                if rootVC is VoiceViewController {
                    let chatRoom = rootVC as! VoiceViewController
                    chatRoom.getConversations()
               // the get Conversations method makes a call to api to get some data then  I reload the whole tableView
                }
            }


    func getConversations() {
    let reachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager()
    if (reachabilityManager?.isReachable)! {
        ServerConnection.getAllConversation { (data) in
            if let _ = data{
                self.conversations = data
                self.onlineRecent = self.conversations
                GlobalMainQueue.async {
                    self.mainTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `getConversation` method which is used in `VoiceViewController` to populate my tableview

Comment: Without seeing all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] it's quite hard to give an exact answer. However, you should definitely update the `getConversations` method of your `VoiceViewController` to make it update only the modified rows instead of the whole table.

Comment: I'd use a notification emitted from the AppDelegate to tell the VoiceViewController, if it's "visible" and listening to update something.

Comment: I've updated my question. The thing is at the moment this works fine..but I don't think it's the best way to do it since I need just to update the UI for a particular cell if I receive a silent Notif

Comment: Your app delegate should not have any knowledge of view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Have the app delegate broadcast an app-specific notification center notification (on the main thread). Have the view controller that contains your table view listen for that notification and update the cell in question as needed. That way you don't contaminate your app delegate. The app delegate should only deal with system level app stuff, not business logic.

Answer (score -2):

You could get your row’s cell using `self.mainTableView.cellForRow(at:IndexPath(…)`, and update it directly.

Or, I’ve found you save a load of time *and* your view controllers end up more reliable using ALTableViewHelper [commercial - available on Framework Central [image: Framework Central] [here](https://frameworkcentral.com/frameworks/ALTableViewHelper/)]. It’s free to try.
The helper does the most of the work - you describe how the data connects to the UITableView. I’ve put together an example (on GitHub [here](https://github.com/JonathanRoach/so-answer-2)), which I hope is something like what you’re trying to do.

```
import ALTableViewHelper
class VoiceViewController {
    // @objc for the helper to see the var’s, and dynamic so it sees any changes to them
    @obj dynamic var conversations: Any?
    @obj dynamic var onlineRequest: Any?

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.setHelperString(“””
        section
            headertext "Conversation Status"
            body
                Conversation
                    $.viewWithTag(1).text <~ conversations[conversations.count-1]["title"]
                    $.viewWithTag(2).text <~ "At \\(dateFormat.stringFromDate(conversations[conversations.count-1]["update"]))"
                UpdateButton
                    $.viewWithTag(1).isAnimating <~ FakeConversationGetter.singleton.busy
        “””, context:self)
    }

    func getConversations() {
        let reachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager()
        if (reachabilityManager?.isReachable)! {
            ServerConnection.getAllConversation { (data) in
            if let _ = data {
                // change the data on the main thread as this causes the UI changes
                GlobalMainQueue.async {
                    self.conversations = data
                    self.onlineRequest = self.conversations
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work to update only one row upon a notification? Your sample does none of that.

Comment: Inside 'setHelperString()' key-value-observation's are set to watch for changes to the data. This is done so that updates to the data cause changes in the UI as described in the helper string. In this case the last element of the conversations array is used to set a label's text, and so changes to the conversations array will cause that label's text (only) to update. It's a bit different to the normal iOS approach - once you've described 'connect this UI to that data' that's almost all of your view controller done - have a look at the sample on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, I downvoted because I don't think it directly answers the question. It requires a whole slew of 3rd party libraries (including your own commercial one) before it works. Furthermore your example on GitHub doesn't compile 'out of the box'.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback. I'll try to make my future answers more focussed on the question. Also, that little feedback on the GitHub project I find very useful - it tells me I need, at least, a requirements section in the readme, and, ideally, the project needs to guide users to downloading Framework Central instead of simply failing. I'll get onto those...